# Filling out a mesh (for Fenics FEM)

Tags: fenics, mesh-generation

I have been using Fenics to model some simple electrostatic problems, but now I need to simulate more complicated geometries. Assuming

- I have created a mesh of several objects, and know their positions in space
- Each node in those objects carries properties of those objects (dielectric constant/etc)

which software and approach should I use to subdivide the free space between these objects (and some bounding box style boundary), so that

- Mesh density depends on distance from objects / geometric complexity
- Fenics will know where the boundary is, and the boundary conditions (zero potential at "infinity")
- Fenics will know the values of charge / dielectric in this free space (set to some default for example)

In my simple problems I have used hand coded functions for determining boundary, calculating boundary conditions, and for objects (such as a capacitor's plates) I have used their geometry to assign charges/etc (for example `if (distance from sphere center < radius) charge = 1.0 else 0`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to `dolfin-convert` script installed within FEniCS, and its manual page,

```
$ man dolfin-convert
```

for supported mesh formats. Then pick some software generating those formats.

Note that cell functions (useful for specifying permitivities in your case) and/or facet functions (useful for boundary and interfacial conditions) are not fully supported by `dolfin-convert` for all formats. To get those details one can dive into `<PYTHONPATH>/dolfin_utils/meshconvert/meshconvert.py` or simply try.

AFAIK, at least [`Triangle`](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) (2D) and [`Gmsh`](http://www.geuz.org/gmsh/) (2D and 3D) formats are quite well supported by `dolfin-convert`.

Comment: thanks, i have been trying with gmsh for the geometry and it seem fine, but i am lost when it comes to defining the cell functions. i'll have a look through the docs when i get my meshes working

Comment: after a bit of mucking around renaming surfaces i got gmsh and dolfin-convert to cooperate